# Is there a way to handle separate input devices for different windowed programs, without losing/switching window focus?

Tags: windows-7, window, gaming, input-device, window-focus

I am trying to work out a solution for a faux-splitscreen setup where there are 4 windowed programs (4 separate instances of a game); each with their own input devices and window focus.

In essence, I am trying to turn one computer and one monitor, into 4-player split-screen, like a console game. This way, 4 players can play the same game, at the same time. Networking is also something that needs to be considered, but I assumed I wouldn't have problem with it.

I have seen software like SoftXpand, but this requires multiple monitors. There is no solution for a single monitor setup, except to window 4 separate instances of the game using a single computer setup.

I have done this before when multi-boxing WoW or Planetside 2. My system can easily run many copies of a game. However, with this setup there is obviously the problem of separate input devices, and window focus.

Is there anything that I can use to assign each individual windowed game instance, its own individual input device, WITHOUT losing focus or constantly having to switch focus?

I need all 4 players to be able to play at the same time on any game I run.

So in the end, this is the setup:

1 Monitor

1 Computer

4 Input Devices

4 Windowed Instances of a Game

1 Network, for multiplayer connectivity for all 4 players.

Comment: So you've already managed to get 4 Windowed instances of the game to run as expected (aside from mouse input problem)?  If so, what solution did you use for that (I ask because it may affect available mouse solutions)?

Comment: Some games can just do it by simply turning off fullscreen. So nothing, just making the video the correct resolution and moving it to the proper area on the screen. Others, will require me to use Sandboxie if I get the error "One instance of this game is already running!".